# SPI timing of 25LC1024

Tags: spi, eeprom

I'm using an EEPROM chip from microchip, [it's doc](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22064B.pdf) gives the read/write timing as below:

[image]

I'm a little confused. From FIGURE 1-2, I think it will read data in at the rising edge of SCK. But from FIGURE 1-3, it only gives a "holding" time (t13) from the falling edge, and the minimum value of \$t_{10}\$ is 50ns, the maximum value of \$t_{13}\$ is 50ns, so it's not safe for master to read data in at rising edge. So I think the the master should better read the data in at the falling edge!! Then this will in conflict with the read timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then make sure the clock speed is a bit less than 20MHz. That way the clock low time \$t_{10}\$ is longer than the "Output valid from clock low" \$t_{13}\$ which will make the bit valid during clock rising edge.

Comment: Which edge should the master read data at? Falling edge? If make t10 longer, then it will be much latter than t13, so apparently, the master can't read data at rising edge, right?

Comment: When the master controlled \$t_{10}\$ is longer than the slave controlled \$t_{13}\$ the rising edge is fine as the data capture point.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. By stretch the clock, make the new data output at the rising edge, right? It seems FIGURE 1-3 is a little misleading.  So, in figure 1-3, the bit read in at rising edge should be the bit after MSB, right?

Comment: @diverger it's very likely that there is a decent margin on both values so even a 20MHz clock and using rising edge will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misreading the data sheet.

T13 is described as "Output valid from clock low" and is a worst case of 50ns (3.3v VCC).

To me this means that the device is clocked on the negative edge and the data is guaranteed to have settled within 50ns.  The master can then clock the data in on the succeeding positive edge.  The clock could be stretched indefinitely and the data would remain.

It is common with SPI interfaces for the slave to clock the data out on one edge of the clock and the master to latch the data on the other.  This provides approximately 50% of the clock period for skew tolerance.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the description of t13, and just saw the figure.